# Firebase giving blank screen due to AuthProvider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I've tried setting up Firebase in my react app a handful of times now, and each time I come to the AuthProvider step it "crashes". Only shows the blank background image. If I delete the AuthProvider stuff from my App.jsx routes it will all come back up. This is my first time messing with Firebase, and so I'm not sure what is going on. Thanks!

Here is my AuthContext component:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthContextProvider({children}) {

    const [ user, setUser ] = useState({})

    function signUp(email, password) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }

    function logIn(email, passwored) {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }

    function logOut() {
        return signOut(auth)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser)
        });
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    })

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{signUp, user }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function UserAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Here is my App.jsx area:

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Password from './pages/Password'
import Signup from './pages/Signup'
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContext'

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/password" element={<Password />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          </Routes>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is the `useEffect` hook used to instantiate the auth listener is missing its dependency array, so each time the auth status is checked and `setUser` is called, the `AuthContextProvider` component rerenders and unsubscribes/resubscribes an auth listener which is likely enqueueing another state update when its initial check completes.

Add an empty dependency array so the listener is instantiated only once when the `AuthContextProvider` component mounts.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, setUser);
  return unsubscribe;
}, []); // <-- empty dependency, run once on mount
```